# drawing pixels in java

Tags: java, pixel, bufferedimage

I have tried again and again to master basic java programming but the phenomenal amount of errors from all of the programs I write has resigned me. This time I am trying to set one pixel and then a series more by adding line after line or a loop.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Points extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    rgb = 0xFF00FF00; // green
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Points points = new Points();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(points);
    frame.setSize(250, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

Points.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
    rgb = 0xFF00FF00; // green
       ^
Points.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);
                ^
Points.java:8: error: illegal start of type
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);
                 ^
Points.java:8: error: illegal start of type
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);
                    ^
Points.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);
                          ^
```

5 errors

In the code section is the error that I get underneath.

Comment: I would recommend a basic Java tutorial, such as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: You forgot to specify the datatype of `rgb`.

Comment: (most likely the datatype shoudl be "int", so the full line would be `int rbg = 0xFF00FF00; // green`)

Comment: He's also trying to call `image.setRGB()` outside of any method.

Comment: The main issue is that you've declared method calls outside of a method. The third line of code you placed under the class declaration should instead be placed inside a constructor (`public Points() {..}`) or elsewhere. Beyond that, you must declare the type of `rgb` (fixable by simply changing it to `int rgb = ..`), as others have mentioned. Overall, I recommend getting used to the basic syntax of the language before trying more complex tasks such as this.

Comment: @MikeB Yupp, and I guess package-private visibility is not intended either (but only there because the OP doesn't really know how classes work)

Answer (score 2):

`rgb` is undefined, so the compiler doesn't know what it should do with it.

You are also trying to execute a piece of code outside of an execution context.

```
public class Points extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    // Invalid decleration, rgb is undefined
    rgb = 0xFF00FF00; // green
    // execution of code outside of a execution context
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);
```

Declare `rgb`

```
int rgb = 0xFF00FF00; // green
```

Move `image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);` to an appropriate execution context, like a method or constructor...

```
public Points () {
    image.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);
```

Also remember, the pixel data is 0 indexed, meaning the first pixel appears at `0x0`

Comment: And read about visiblity modifiers. YOu might want to add "private" to some or all of your member variables.

Answer (score -1):

setRGB method takes third argument as `int rgb`
Lets say you want to color your pixel green

You have to create object of type Color first

```
Color myGreenColor=new Color(255,0,0);
```

Then you can set it to image like

```
image.setRGB(i,j,myGreenColor.getRGB());
```

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. Wyh do you have to specify a color object first, only to get an int out o that? the value of `rbg` specified by the OP is fine and a valid color.

Comment: Sorry Ziker. That part the OP is doing correct, technically. The main issue is where they are doing it, which is causing their errors.